# AVPlayer seektoTime iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avfoundation, avplayer

I have used seekToTime in my application and its working properly. But I want to have some more information about it. Which is, if I have a streaming video file of 1 minute now I want to play it from second 15th to second 45 (first 15 seconds and the last 15 seconds will not play).

How can I do it?

I know that by use of seekToTime I can play a video from 15th second but how to stop it at 45th second and also get noticed by the method that the video has played for the specified time period?

```
CMTime timer = CMTimeMake(15, 1);
[player seekToTime:timer];
```

The above code takes me to the 15th second of the streaming file but how to stop it on 45th second and get notified too?

I have searched a lot but couldn't get any info.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As @codeghost suggested, simply use `forwardPlaybackEndTime`.

You can simply use:

```
yourAVPlayerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(10, 1);
```

Here 10 is the time till the AVPlayerItem will play.

Comment: does forwardPlaybackEndTime work for you?

Comment: Yes it worked, had to implement some logics and it started working as per my requirement

Comment: can you take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717819/forwardplaybackendtime-does-not-work ? The player still plays to the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `forwardPlaybackEndTime` property on your AVPlayerItem.

Comment: thanks codeghost, How can I use it in my code, do you have any reference link for example/tutorial related to this forwardPlaybackEndTime

Comment: Check out the Playback system guid in Xcode, but all you should need to do is set it, e.g. "playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(45, 1);". Create an AVQueuePlayer with your AVPlayerItem and play as you are today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is something build-in for this in `AVPlayer`, but what i would do is build an function and call it with :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopPlaying) withObject:nil afterDelay:45];


-(void)stopPlaying{
   [player pause];
}
```

this will stop playing after 45 seconds,and of course you can put instead 45 any number of seconds that you want.

Comment: You are right this is another way around to stop the player, but as codeghost suggested forwardPlaybackEndTime, I am looking for it that how to use it in the code, but till now haven't got any code snippet or example. Apple's documentation is poor related to AVFoundation. Its too difficult to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[AVPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:]` for that purpose.

Get the `AVPlayer.currentTime` periodically, and call pause or stop on the exact time.