# forwardPlaybackEndTime does not work

Tags: ios, time, avplayer, forward, avplayeritem

`AVPlayerItem` has this property `forwardPlaybackEndTime`

> The value indicated the time at which playback should end when the
>   playback rate is positive (see AVPlayer’s rate property).
>
> The default value is kCMTimeInvalid, which indicates that no end time
>   for forward playback is specified. In this case, the effective end
>   time for forward playback is the item’s duration.

But I don't know why it does not work. I tried to set it in `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`, duration available callback, ... but it does not have any effect, it just plays to the end

I think that `forwardPlaybackEndTime` is used to restrict the playhead, right?
In my app, I want to play from the beginning to the half of the movie only

My code looks like this

```
- (void)playURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:URL];

    if (self.avPlayer) {
        if (self.avPlayer.currentItem && self.avPlayer.currentItem != playerItem) {
            [self.avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        }
    } else {
        [self setupAVPlayerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    }

    playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);

    // Play
    [self.avPlayer play];
}
```

How to make `forwardPlaybackEndTime` work?

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   AVPlayerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);
   Here 5 is the time till the AVPlayerItem will play.
```

Comment: I already set that, but the player still plays to the end of the movie. I aslo `CMTimeShow(avplayerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime)` and see that my configure was right

Comment: check this `AVCaptureConnection *conn = [output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
CMTimeShow(conn.videoMinFrameDuration);
CMTimeShow(conn.videoMaxFrameDuration);
if (conn.supportsVideoMinFrameDuration)
    conn.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
if (conn.supportsVideoMaxFrameDuration)
    conn.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, CAPTURE_FRAMES_PER_SECOND);
CMTimeShow(conn.videoMinFrameDuration);
CMTimeShow(conn.videoMaxFrameDuration);`

Comment: u have to set maximum and minimum duration

Comment: AVPlayerItem does not have maximum/minimum properties ?!

Comment: it is live streaming video or video play from local

Comment: it is live streaming/progressive download

Comment: try this `Float64 dur = CMTimeGetSeconds([avPlayer currentTime])-2.0;
    CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(dur, avPlayer.currentTime.timescale);
    [avPlayer seekToTime:newTime];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60871/discussion-between-onmyway133-and-ramesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Set the following on your AVPlayer

```
AVPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Then set your notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidPlayToEndTime:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
```

with the method obviously

```
- (void) playerItemDidPlayToEndTime:(NSNotification*)notification
{
// do something here
}
```

then set your forwardPlaybackEndTime

```
AVPlayer.currentItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeAdd(AVPlayer.currentItem.currentTime, CMTimeMake(5.0, 1));
```

and start your avplayer playing

```
AVPlayer.rate = 1.0;
```

the notification will be triggered and your track will continue playing. In your handler you can stop it and do a seekToTime or whatever.

Alternatively you can just set a boundary observer

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5.0, 1)]];


    __weak OTHD_AVPlayer* weakself = self;
    self.observer_End = [self addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:array queue:NULL usingBlock:^{ if( weakself.rate >= 0.0 )     [weakself endBoundaryHit]; }];
```

Comment: why ``actionAtItemEnd``, ``AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification``? I think forwardPlaybackEndTime is used to restrict the playhead? Say I only want to play from the beginning to the half of the movie, how can I do that with ``forwardPlaybackEndTime``

Comment: actionAtItemEnd tells the AVPlayer what to do when it hits the end - you want it to do nothing. The AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification is triggered when the AVPlayer hits your forwardPlaybackEndTime so you want to be watching for this.

Comment: This approach seems logical, but it just doesn't work for me.  The video ends; the event triggers; and I'm able to set the new rate and forwardPlaybackEndTime, but the video always restarts at the beginning instead of continuing from where it stopped  Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: @Axeva - yes that's the expected behaviour. If you need it to play on from a point just having changed the rate I'd suggest my alternative of using a boundary observer.

Comment: I don't really care about changing the rate.  That was just a tip I found somewhere else that didn't work.  I really just want to play the video to a certain point, stop it until a user action happens, then resume.  Boundary observers are a lot more messy than forwardPlaybackEndTime, and not as precise.  Is that really the only option?

Comment: @Axeva - in your playerItemDidPlayToEndTime: method you could call the AVPlayer seekToTime: method with your new start time and set your rate to 1.0 (or call play) in the completionHandler.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer.  `seekToTime` isn't enough.  You need `seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter`.  See also [Resume AVPlayer after forwardPlaybackEndTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225334/resume-avplayer-after-forwardplaybackendtime)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked below code its running and streaming stops at specified time:

```
- (void)playURL
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"];

self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

self.playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(10, 1);

self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];

[videoView setPlayer:self.avPlayer];

// Play
[self.avPlayer play];
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Also please check these tutorials: [AVFoundation Framework](http://www.sdkboy.com/category/avfoundation-framework/)

Comment: your video URL works, it seems forwardPlaybackEndTime only works for certain URLs/streams

Comment: No, it should work with all streams, previously I had to stream video clips from S3, and those worked fine, even I had to stream multiple files without any gap in between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to update `avPlayer's current playerItem`.

So,

```
 playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);
```

it should be:

```
 self.avPlayer.currentItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);
```

Comment: I think 

""self.avPlayer.playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);""

creates a new playerItem and assigns the new playerItem to self.avplayer.

But,

""playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);""

just creates a new playerItem. It doesn't assign the new playerItem to self.avPlayer. So self.avPlayer doesn't know the new playerItem, it will still play the old playerItem.

I think that probably playerItem is called by value not by reference.

Comment: Instead of "self.avPlayer.playerItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);", It should be "self.avPlayer.currentItem.forwardPlaybackEndTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1);".